# PhoneGap + HTML5 database

Tags: html, cordova

I am developing an iPhone/Android app using PhoneGap and thinking to use HTMl5 WebSQL database to store data locally. What are the risks involved using HTML 5 WebSQL databse on mobile devices?

One i found that the performance on iPhone is slower compare to Sqlite databse. 
Is there any security concern?

Thank you

Comment: Another thing to note, is WebSQL is not being actively developed  anymore - http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ So it's not the best future-proof method to use.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend this manual, that was useful for me.

[Coenraets.org](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/)

Is the best implementation i found over the net, it helps to create a persistent solution for phonegap storage.

Greetings.